# htaccess with redirect page in php

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I write the following code on htaccess

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /localhost_site_name/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ ?page=$1 [L]


# 404 redirect page start

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ error.php [L]

#404 redirect page end
```

I am displaying pages based on page concept so I will check the page before to displaying that details on page. 
This is my index file

```
    <?php
        session_start();
        ob_start();
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>

        <body>

        <?php 
          //echo "Page name is ".$page;

        if($page=="template" || $page=="user")
        {

               include("modal.php");
               include("topnav.php");

               include("sidebarnav.php");

               include("content.php");
               include("footer.php");

        }
        else
        {
            echo "<h1 style='background:#000;color:#fff;'>404 Error</h1>";
        }


        ?>

        </body>

    </html>
```

Now my problem is when i display the pages with one argument based on my page name its shows correctly
But when i try to pass argument with that it always went to 404 page
I couldn't find out that why its happening
So help me to pass two argument with htaccess used on page concept

working url: http://localhost/sitename/pagename/

not working url: http://localhost/sitename/pagename/argument